# Через время закрывается программа, выполняется бесконечный цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Программа в бесконечном цикле проверят соответствует ли текущее время указанной в документе .csv, если да то выполняется команда открытия ссылки. Точно так же если наступило время завершения что указанно в документе .csv, то браузер закрывается.
Я собрал через pyinstaller .exe программу, она работает около часа и после закрывается. Прошу помогите понять, что может быть причиной. Тут ссылка на [nama.csv](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/BgFt2FX8Nlijyw)

```
def CSV_time():#Из CSV файла переменные получают время
while True:

    day = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")  # Получает текущую дату, месяц и год

    with open("nama.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=";")
        for row in reader:
            if row['data'] == day:  # Если в списке есть такая дата
                time_namaz1 = row['time1_off']
                time_namaz2 = row['time2_off']
                time_namaz3 = row['time3_off']
                time_namaz4 = row['time4_off']

                time_radio1 = row['time1_on']
                time_radio2 = row['time2_on']
                time_radio3 = row['time3_on']
                time_radio4 = row['time4_on']

                TIME_on = row['time_on']
                TIME_off = row['time_off']

                while True:

                    TIME = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%H:%M:%S")

                    if TIME == TIME_on:  # on
                        if not "msedge.exe" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
                            webbrowser.open('https://www.govoritmaykop.ru', new=0)
                        time.sleep(1)
                    if TIME == time_namaz1:  # off
                        os.system('taskkill /IM msedge.exe /F')
                        time.sleep(1)
                    if TIME == time_radio1:  # on
                        if not "msedge.exe" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
                            webbrowser.open('https://www.govoritmaykop.ru', new=0)
                        time.sleep(1)
                    if TIME == time_namaz2:  # off
                        os.system('taskkill /IM msedge.exe /F')
                        time.sleep(1)
                    if TIME == time_radio2:  # on
                        if not "msedge.exe" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
                            webbrowser.open('https://www.govoritmaykop.ru', new=0)
                        time.sleep(1)
                    if TIME == time_namaz3:  # off
                        os.system('taskkill /IM msedge.exe /F')
                        time.sleep(1)
                    if TIME == time_radio3:  # on
                        if not "msedge.exe" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
                            webbrowser.open('https://www.govoritmaykop.ru', new=0)
                        time.sleep(1)
                    if TIME == time_namaz4:  # off
                        os.system('taskkill /IM msedge.exe /F')
                        time.sleep(1)
                    if TIME == time_radio4:  # on
                        if not "msedge.exe" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
                            webbrowser.open('https://www.govoritmaykop.ru', new=0)
                        time.sleep(1)
                    if TIME > TIME_on and TIME < time_namaz1:
                        if not "msedge.exe" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
                            webbrowser.open('https://www.govoritmaykop.ru', new=0)
                    if TIME == TIME_off or TIME > TIME_off:
                        if "msedge.exe" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
                            os.system('taskkill /IM msedge.exe /F')
                    if TIME < TIME_on:
                        if "msedge.exe" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
                            os.system('taskkill /IM msedge.exe /F')
                    else:
                        break # Выход из цикла для обновления даты
```

Comment: Ну, вам нужно получить ошибку для начала.

Comment: Азамат Джан, скажи, а что прога будет делать при условии `TIME > TIME_on` и `TIME > time_namaz1`. У тебя это условие не учтено, значит происходит частый выход из внутреннего цикла. Следовательно, очень быстро открывается и закрывается файл на чтение. Возможно, проблема в этом. Наверняка сказать сложно, не запустив приложение для теста. А это невозможно без данных файла .csv.
Есть пожелание выделить код открытия и закрытия браузера в отдельные функции.

Comment: HerrAskin, if TIME > TIME_on and TIME < time_namaz1: если время больше чем 08:00:00 часов и меньше чем 12:10:00 часов то выполняется проверка запущен ли браузер, если нет то запускает.

WTFisGoingOn, запустил код на pycharm, подожду пару часов. Надеюсь что ошибка в *.exe будет воспроизведена в компиляторе.

Comment: на сегодняшний день я узнал что из .py лучше не делать exe, сборка идет не правильно и много еще не очень понятных моментов связано с этим. А мне нужен exe чтобы отслеживать его через бота, включать и выключать, а PID или ID процесса я так понял динамическая, зарание знать нельзя чтобы записать в бота. В любом случае я продолжу и на ночь оставлю скрипт запущенным. Как что отпишусь, надеюсь сам скрипт хоть будет работать. Я далек от программиста но точно понял что выбрал не тот язык для изучения, скриптование не для меня

Comment: Без сборки в .exe программа закрывается или штатно крутится?

Comment: Amgarak я запустил .py на ночь и утром обнаружил что она закрыта. Опять ставлю на pycharm, буду ждать до обеда.

Comment: .py файл в pycharm не дает никаких ошибок. exe работает максимум до 2х часов а .py файл запущенный напрямую работает от 4х часов до максимум 7-8 часов.

Comment: Поймал [ошибку](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/BXcFkztSu9pPGw) воспроизводится на .py файле именно в ночное время после 01.00 часов ночи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибку вызывал PID программы msedge.exe:

```
psutil.NoSuchProcess: process no longer exists (pid=ххххх)
```

Нашел [тему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74420568/error-psutil-nosuchprocess-process-no-longer-exists-pid-23100) с подобной ошибкой, что очень помогло.
63 и 66-ю строку заменил на упакованную функцию

```
def TRACK_ON_AND_OFF():
try:
    if "msedge.exe" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
        os.system('taskkill /IM msedge.exe /F')
    else:
        pass
except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
    pass
```

PS Новичкам, чтобы найти ошибку самозавершения можно просто запустив скрипт через CMD или любой другой интерпретатор(вот только pycharm не давал ошибок, там все работало как часы).